# Ubuntu 14.04 with Node.js connection refused on routes

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

Using Express, I created a route `/users` which outputs some random strings. It works fine on my local machine. However, if I deploy my app on DigitalOcean, while viewing IP:port works, if I try my new route IP:port/users the server responds with "connection refused."

Any ideas what I am missing?

Here are the results of `netstat`:

[image: Netstat]

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without knowing how you're routing etc

Answer (score 0):

I was searching in the wrong place...  it was the first time I got a `connection refused` from a server on an actual database error. I removed everything from the actual route and just used plain text as an output. The problem was simple just a misconfiguration of the mysql connection and the database itself.

Thanks anyway for the fast response and for putting my weird English words into the right order.